# "unfortunately adobe air has stopped"

Tags: adobe-air

I decided to hard reset my huawei y511 due to some personal reason. Now, since then everytime i log in to google at midst of my browsing it pops up "unfortunately air has stopped" and it goes over and over. Please help me how to resolve this? thanks a lot

Comment: Can you uninstall then reinstall Adobe Air? AFAIK, it's not a system app, but I'm not sure on Huawei devices.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your applications including Adobe Air is up to date, if they are uninstall and reinstall Adobe Air.

Additionally make sure you phone's RAM and CPU usage isn't too high. You can check this by going into `settings > application`, and the `running` tab.

Comment: That's a very general advice and it doesn't tell us what could be causing the issue. Please be specific.