# 'unfortunately stopped' problem

Tags: applications, notifications

My Gionee M2 is showing **error messages** often.

1. "unfortunately ikeyboard has stopped"
2. "unfortunately systeminfo has stopped"
3. "unfortunately adobe air has stopped"
4. "unfortunately measure has stopped"

It started suddenly. I can't use the phone at all. I've done following things,

1. I have done factory reset but no help.
2. I rooted the phone and uninstalled Adobe Air, systeminfo and ikeyboard using kingroot.

But unfortunately this issue is coming back automatically and the phone specification are as follows.

[image: system status]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxwHg.png)

Comment: Related: ["unfortunately adobe air has stopped"](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/124266)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unfortunately xxx has stopped"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131710/unfortunately-xxx-has-stopped)

Answer (score -1):

Your phone infected with a trojan. Not a permanant solution yet

use   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.security.stubborntrjkiller app to remove the virus

Comment: Please explain  (in detail) how did you conclude that the phone is infected with a trojan and how exactly that app is able to purge the trojan. We need details to understand the issue at hand, not some dependence on third-party apps.