# "Unfortunately xxx has stopped"

Tags: system-error, force-close

My Symphony Xplorer W85 running JellyBean v.4.2.2 suddenly began showing the following errors, making the phone unusable:

- "unfortunately ikeyboard has stopped"
- "unfortunately systeminfo has stopped"
- "unfortunately adobe air has stopped"
- "unfortunately measure has stopped"

I first tried factory resetting the phone, then rooted and uninstalled Adobe Air, systeminfo, and ikeyboard using Kingroot but the phone still displays the errors. What might be causing this and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Reflash your stock ROM.

Comment: You might be dealing with an issue similar to this: [Attempted multiple solutions for malwares like androidSystem, timeService and monkeyTest, but to no avail](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125408)

Answer (score 2):

Download the stock Rom and re-flash

Here is the link:

http://firmwarefile.com/symphony-w25

Answer (score -2):

Probably this happens if you try to flash files which are not supported.
Did you try to flash something?

This could fix it-
Download the stock firmware for your device and then flash it.

Comment: For your first line, I recommend you read this again: "***I first tried factory resetting the phone**, then rooted and uninstalled Adobe Air, systeminfo, and ikeyboard using Kingroot but the phone still displays the errors.*"

Comment: Okay,so the possible solution here is to flash the stock rom again to get the device back to its normal state.

Comment: Yes, but [we already know that info](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/131737/96277).

Comment: Cool then,just tried to help.